# problem adding code into wp editor for https://wordpress.org/support

Tags: editor

i need to add long code into the https://wordpress.org/support site but it corrupted maybe because using ` into my codes like this:

https://wordpress.org/support/?post_type=topic&p=12215312

[image]

so how could i insert my codes and quotes into my question correctly?

thanks.

Comment: You should ask this in the wordpress.org forum. Our site is independent from wordpress.org.

Comment: yes i have done it could be seen [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-adding-code-into-wp-form-you-can-source-code-in-editor-for-https-wordp/)